# Correlation in case of double measurements, where one is incorrect

Tags: correlation

Assuming the following scenario:

There are N samples with M continuous features each **(N < M)**. Each sample gets measured twice. One of the measurements is correct, the other one is uncorrelated with the true values. It is i.i.d. if the first or second measurement is correct for each sample. Each sample is also associated with a (correctly measured) response variable. Do statistical methods exist that can correlate features with the response variable under these circumstances?

Comment: *"It is i.i.d. if the first or second measurement is correct for each sample"* I do not understand this sentence

Comment: *"One of the measurements is correct"* what do you mean by 'correct'?

Comment: *"Each sample is also associated with a (correctly measured) response variable."* what do you mean by response variable? How does that variable look like? What sort of association does it have?

Comment: *"can correlate features with the response variable under these circumstances?"* What do you mean by 'correlate'? Like compute a Pearson correlation for a feature and the response variable? If both are numeric variables then you can always compute a correlation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you add the two measurements of a feature, then you will have a total that is very noisy. But it will still be correlated with the response, just more weakly. You would do this for each feature.